# C# - Timer in UI Thread

Tags: c#, synchronization

There is a timer that is executed once per second.

This timer takes 0.5 seconds to execute once.

If you click another button while the function of this timer is running, I wonder if the timer stops immediately or if another operation is performed after the timer is done.

Also, in the opposite case, when the button is clicked and the function is operating, it is also wondered if the function of the timer should operate after 1 second.

```
System.Windows.Form.Timer TestTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
TestTimer.Interval = 1000;
TestTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.TestTimerFunc);

private void TestTimerFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // 0.5 sec
}

System.Windows.Forms.Button TestButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
TestButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.TestButtonFunc);

private void TestButtonFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // 5 sec
}
```

Comment: Timers does not run on the UI thread. they run in their own thread. As for System.Windows.Forms.Timer, if memory serves, it's Click event handler does run on the UI thread - so clicking the button should not take effect while the click event handler is running it's code, but only after it's done.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, If my memory serves right `System.Windows.Form.Timer` runs on UI thread

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) says that this timer lives in single-threaded environment (on UI thread). It just raises a **Tick** event at specific **Interval** and relays on window message pump for counting (so it has accuracy of 55ms). It will not "stop" until its **Enabled** property is **true**.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü seems like I was wrong about this specific timer. I assumed it was a component wrapping `System.Threading.Timer` (like `System.Timers.Timer`).

Comment: Your GUI, including the Timer, is single-threaded and events are not pre-emptive. So this should work, except that the Timer won't fire when the button handler is running.

Comment: There is an important guidline you are treading on here: Every event should be handled in less than 100ms. Above that, use Tasks or (pool) Threads.